# Visual Force page display name of given Id

Tags: apex, visualforce

ok i have this:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Provider">
  <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!o.WhoId}">{!o.WhoId}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

this returns me this html:

```
<a href="https://cs14.salesforce.com/003i000000Rs7wgAAB" target="_blank">003i000000Rs7wgAAB</a>
```

I need this html:

```
<a href="https://cs14.salesforce.com/003i000000Rs7wgAAB" target="_blank">Lead Name</a>
```

the object in question 'o' is a task.

lastly if i change my code to this:

```
<apex:column value="{!o.WhoId}"/>
```

I get the appropriate response, but i dont get the target="_blank" i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{!o.Who.Name}` to output the name of the record.

Comment: Content cannot be displayed: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Task.Who.

Comment: and if i query it like this:
Select t.Id, t.Description, t.Who, t.Subject, t.WhoId From Task

Comment: i get this error:
Save error: No such column 'Who' on entity 'Task'. If you are attempting to use a custom field

Comment: You need to query e.g. `t.who.name` to get the data you want. You can't just query `t.who` because it's a relationship field.

Comment: you are the man ! thumbs up 4 u